# Error in property of NSString Object when using in different method of same class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I made a property of NSString and initialised it in a function of the class.
Now I am using NSLog() another function , to show what this string contains.

Instead of getting what I entered, I am getting weird string.
My code listing was following:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringWithProperty;
```

Now in implementation:

```
  - (IBAction)FirstButtonPressed:(id)sender
{   

NSString *x= [labelForSecondLine.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString *y= [labelForSecondLine.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)];
NSString *z= [labelForSecondLine.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)];

stringWithProperty=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-20%@",x,y,z];

}

- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@",stringWithProperty);
}
```

When I press second button after pressing first, I get this output:

```
<UIButtonContent: 0x71533b0 Title = (null), AttributedTitle = (null), Image = (null), Background = (null), TitleColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1, ShadowColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.5>
```

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong with me or with this code?

Comment: Try to use self.stringWithProperty

Comment: Show us the corresponding `@synthesize` statement, if you have one.

Comment: yes of course..
I did synthesize that property
..  @synthesize stringWithProperty

Comment: Have you tried using `self.stringWithProperty`?  (Especially where you assign the value to the property.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are weird, until you get used to them.  (In fact, they're weird even after you get used to them.)

Complicating matters is the fact that Apple keeps playing with the way properties work.

If you want to be relatively independent of compiler version, and avoid assorted oddities, insert `@synthesize stringWithProperty;` just below your `@implementation` statement, and *always* refer to the property as `self.stringWithProperty`.  In later versions of the compiler these steps are unnecessary, but there is no harm in them.

Comment: yes of course..
I did synthesize that property
..  @synthesize stringWithProperty

Answer (score 0):

if there is no `@synthesize stringWithProperty=stringWithProperty;` for property, underlaying variable name will be set to `_stringWithProperty`. You're hitting some object with same name (looks like it is some button content). Use `self.stringWithProperty` to access property or (if you really need to do so) `_stringWithProperty` to access it's variable directly (or maybe even better more explicit `self->_stringWithProperty`)

Comment: DO NOT use `_stringWithProperty` or `self ->_stringWithProperty` to assign a value to the property!!!

Comment: I do agree (unless you're playing with custom getter/setter)

Comment: yes of course..
I did synthesize that property
..  @synthesize stringWithProperty

Comment: synthesized or not, always use with `self` to avoid such situations when you're accidentally hitting something not really wanted.

Comment: also it's highly recommended to not access that underlaying variable directly if there is no need to do so, use property as property ;)